# How to how to add a flag to an Angular start script in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

In an answer to another question, it was suggested that someone add this flag to the start script, but it does not explain how to do this.

***"start": "ng serve --host=127.0.0.1"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it in launch.json after the url entry.